# удалить позицию

Tags: android, recyclerview, position

Есть RecyclerView в нем данные id и Price,нахожу максимальное число Price среди всех позиций, и пытаюсь удалить

```
     Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int max=0;
            for(int i=0;i<arrayT.length;i++){
                if(arrayT[i] > max){
                    max = arrayT[i];
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(max), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dataModels.remove(max);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, 4000);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Но есть проблема ,например max Price =300 но а id позиции которое соответствует max Price  равна 2.Как получить позицию id ?

Answer (score 1):

```
int max=0;
int iOfMax=0;
for(int i=0;i<arrayT.length;i++){
    if(arrayT[i] > max){
        max = arrayT[i];
        iOfMax = i;
    }
}
```